# RxJava interrupt parallel execution when first result found

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I am running some service working with delay in parallel. The task is to not wait while all services have finished execution.

```
    Observable.just(2, 3, 5)
                .map(delay -> serviceReturningSingleWithDelay(delay))
                .toList()
                .flatMap(list ->
                        Single.zip(list, output -> Arrays.stream(output)
                                .map(delay -> (Integer) delay)
                                .filter(delay -> delay == 3)
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElse(0)
                        ))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

```
 private Single<Integer> serviceReturningSingleWithDelay(Integer delay) {
        return Single.just(delay)
                .delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .doOnSuccess(s -> System.out.printf("Delay %d: Thread : %s \n", delay, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }
```

Now my output is:

```
Delay 2: Thread : RxComputationThreadPool-1 
Delay 3: Thread : RxComputationThreadPool-2 
Delay 5: Thread : RxComputationThreadPool-3 
3
```

The desired result is to obtain filtered value - 3 before *RxComputationThreadPool-3* thread finished execution.
I will be thankful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run them all in parallel and exit when you receive value 3, you don't need to use `zip`. Rather use `takeWhile` to interrupt your observable like the following :

```java
Observable.just(2, 3, 5)
          .flatMapSingle(this::serviceReturningSingleWithDelay)
          .takeWhile(e -> e != 3)
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

And if you want the `3` value use `takeUntil(e -> e == 3)` instead of `takeWhile(e -> e != 3)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way based on @bubbles answer. If you want to keep the `flatmap` and in Kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Observable.just(5L, 8L, 10L)
            .flatMap {
                serviceReturningSingleWithDelay(it).toObservable()
            }
            .takeWhile { delay -> delay != 8L }
            .subscribeBy(
                    onNext = { println("Delay period $it")}
            )

    Thread.sleep(10000)
}

private fun serviceReturningSingleWithDelay(delay: Long): Single<Long> {
    return Single.just(delay)
            .delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnSuccess {
                println("Delay $it Thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }
}
```